# How to navigate within the app in a hyperlink text click?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a text bound to a label contains a `<a>Click here</a>` anchor tag. The text Click here is displayed as hyperlink. I want to navigate to a page within the app when the hyperlink is clicked.

How to do this?

I tried implementing Custom `Label` renderer, but couldn't achieve exactly my goal.

Comment: Link to what? A Form's page? An external browser? or?

Comment: @SushiHangover Form page.

Comment: You could use ValueConverter for separating the link from the bounded text if your anchor tag placement is static. I have used a custom view where you could change the string formatting code to fit any scenario of yours.

Comment: You need to inject javascript from your html code if you want to open an Xamarin Page.

Comment: Could you share more code about question to explain how to invoke the hyperlink ?

Comment: @SümeyyaTuğçeArar Can you pls provide me an example.

Comment: @Sankarann You can follow this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview)

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you could use a `TapGestureRecognizer` and remove the anchor tag by converting the bound text it could be way much simpler Using a custom view. Add a bindable property for the link text and another for Navigation command.

**CustomView.Xaml**

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <Label x:Name="linkTextLabel"/>
</ContentView.Content>
```

**CustomView.Xaml.cs**

```
public string TextWithlink
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextWithlinkProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextWithlinkProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextWithlinkProperty = BindableProperty.Create("TextWithlink", typeof(string), typeof(LinkText), "", BindingMode.Default, propertyChanged: OnTextLinkChanged);

    public Command NavigationCommand
    {
        get { return (Command)GetValue(NavigationCommandProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(NavigationCommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty NavigationCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create("NavigationCommand", typeof(Command), typeof(LinkText), null, BindingMode.Default, propertyChanged: OnNavigationCommandChanged);

    private static void OnNavigationCommandChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newValue)
    {
        (bindable as LinkText).ChangeCommand();
    }

    private static void OnTextLinkChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newValue)
    {
        (bindable as LinkText).Changetext();
    }

    private void ChangeCommand()
    {
        linkTapGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        linkTapGesture.Command = this.NavigationCommand;
        linkSpan.GestureRecognizers.Clear();
        linkSpan.GestureRecognizers.Add(linkTapGesture);
    }

    private void Changetext()
    {
        FormattedString formattedString = new FormattedString();

        /// String formatting code, change according to your need
        string[] subStrings = this.TextWithlink.Split('<');
        Span textSpan = new Span()
        {
            Text = subStrings[0] + " "
        };

        string linkString = subStrings[1].Split('>')[1];

        linkSpan = new Span()
        {
            Text = linkString,
        };

        ///

        formattedString.Spans.Add(textSpan);
        formattedString.Spans.Add(linkSpan);
        this.linkTextLabel.FormattedText = formattedString;
    }
```

Usage.Xaml

```
<local:LinkText
            TextWithlink="{Binding TextWithLink}" NavigationCommand="{Binding NavigationCommand}"/>
```

2. But if you want the app to be navigated via a hyperlink. Since, the link redirects are handled by the Mobile OS, consider custom uri redirects. This [blog](https://xamarinhelp.com/uri-scheme/) might help you.

For Android, [deep link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

For iOS, [custom URI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app)

IMHO the URI navigation could be a bit more work for navigation within the App.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a Xamarin Forms Page from a html, you need to use javascript injection. You can find a good documentation and sample in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview).